# Is it possible to redirect the initiator of a Signature Request to Docusign for him/her to proceed with preparing the envelope before sending it out

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am in the process of developing a specialized middleware application with the primary function of receiving documents from a designated API. Subsequently, these documents are transmitted to Docusign's platform to initiate signature requests.

My inquiry pertains to a specific functionality I am aiming to implement. I intend for the application to seamlessly redirect the initiator to Docusign's "New Envelope" page. The objective here is to facilitate the process of adding and editing recipients for the envelope. This redirection would be accompanied by the preloading of the designated document into the system.

I am seeking clarity on the feasibility of this approach. If indeed possible, I am interested in understanding the steps or procedures required to achieve this seamless redirection and preloading of the document within Docusign's environment.

I've successfully incorporated Docusign's SDK into my project. This integration allows me to generate an envelope, include recipients, and utilize the SDK to transmit the document to all intended recipients. However, my objective is to take this a step further.

I'm aiming to seamlessly redirect initiators to Docusign's "New Envelope" page from within my application. This would enable initiators to personally designate signing locations for each recipient directly on the document. Once these placements are specified, the user would have the capability to finalize the process by sending out the envelope to the chosen recipients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe what you want to do is what we call "embedded sending" and we show you how to do this in the [How to send an envelope via your app](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embedded-sending/) code example.

This is a different kind of [EnvelopeView](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/) called [SenderView](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createsender/) and you generate a URL for it which you can then embed in your app and let your user go to it to complete the sending of the envelope.

The code example showing how to do this using C# SDK is on GitHub - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/EmbeddedSending.cs